# fill jcombobox from database depending on text from textfield

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtextfield, jcombobox

I want to fill the jComboBox with values from database. and these values depend on the text written in the textfield. 
eg: if I write a in the texfield, the combobox will have all values starting with a. The values are from a databse

Here's my code:

```
private void FillCombo(){
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pharmacy";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String user = "root";
String pass = "test";
String sql = "select medicinename from medicine where medicinename like '%"+jTextField5.getText()+"%'"; 

try{

    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    System.out.println("1");
    Connection con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
    System.out.println("Connected");
    Statement st=(Statement) con.createStatement();        
    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
    String name = rs.getString("medicinename");
    jComboBox1.addItem(name);

    }

} catch(Exception e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);    

}}
```

Comment: remove ending `%` if you are talking about start with only.

Comment: I want not just one caracter 
eg:  if i write a, as, asp it fill aspirine
myproblem is that the combobox is already filled.
 want it empty when i start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want not just one caracter eg: if i write a, as, asp it fill aspirine myproblem is that the combobox is already filled. want it empty when i start.

Simply use [JComboBox#removeAllItems()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#removeAllItems%28%29) to removes all items from the item list on each stroke of any key in the `JTextField`.

### Points to Remember

- **Don't** load driver each time you enter a new character. Move it outside the `FillCombo()` method.
- Use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of using single quoted query string that may cause issue. Find a sample on [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
- **Don't** forget to close the resources such as connection, result set and statement.
- Use finally block to handle it or Read more about [Java7 -The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)